# Google Plus Logout button not working

Tags: android, android-activity, google-plus

I have followed the quick start sample app from google developer site https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android and it worked pretty well with sign in button, signout and revoke buttons on the same activity.

But when I tried to move the signout button to new activity and calls the signout button it started crashing.

This is what I'm trying to do :

```
  @Override
  public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    // Reaching onConnected means we consider the user signed in.
    Log.i(TAG, "onConnected");

    // Update the user interface to reflect that the user is signed in.


    // Retrieve some profile information to personalize our app for the user.
    Person currentUser = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);

    mStatus.setText(String.format(
        getResources().getString(R.string.signed_in_as),
        currentUser.getDisplayName()));

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, LogOutActivityty.class);   
    //myIntent.putExtra("GUsername", currentUser.getDisplayName());    
    startActivity(myIntent);

    // Indicate that the sign in process is complete.
    mSignInProgress = STATE_DEFAULT;
  }
```

This is my LogOut Activity:

```
 Logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button);

    Logout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
                mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
               Intent i = new Intent(LogOutActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
               startActivity(i);
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logged out using Google Account", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat ?

Comment: This 'if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected())' fails so nothing happens. Make sure that the client is connected 1st.